# Subtrair valores usando o sqlite no Python

Tags: python, sql

Eu quero fazer o seguinte:

Criar uma função com um parâmetro quantidade,assim fazendo com que o valor do parâmetro subtraia com um valor de um campo da tabela:

Exemplo: vender(5), esse 5 vai subtrair com campo quantidade da tabela.

O mais perto que eu cheguei, foi:

```
def vender(self, nome, quantidade):
    consulta = 'UPDATE OR IGNORE Produtos SET quantidade = quantidade-1'
    self.cursor.execute(consulta, ())
    self.conexao.commit()
```

Só que nesse caso ele diminui 1 em 1.

Comment: Oi, voce está subtraindo quantidade-1, tens primeiro consultar a quantidade e ao resultado subtrair a quantidade.

Comment: Olá, o modo que o G.Bittencourt postou abaixo resolveu o problema, só que agora está dando conflito com a função cadastrar, quando vou cadastrar um produto da o seguinte erro....self.cursor.execute(consulta, (nome,categoria,valor,quantidade))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

Comment: Consegui resolver, só faltou eu abrir e fechar parenteses dentro do VALUES ?,?,?,? resultando em VALUES(?,?,?,?)...Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode passar a variável `quantidade` na sua variável de query:

`consulta = "UPDATE OR IGNORE Produtos SET quantidade = quantidade - %d" %quantidade`

Comment: Olá, deu certo muitooo obrigado, mas ocorreu um erro em outra parte do programa.

Na hora de cadastrar um produto aparece o seguinte erro....

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ayrton/Documentos/Loja/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    banco.cadastrar('Iphone', 'Celular', 2.100, 100)
  File "/home/ayrton/Documentos/Loja/produtos.py", line 12, in cadastrar
    self.cursor.execute(consulta, (nome,categoria,valor,quantidade))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error..... Isso ocorreu logo após essa edição que você sugeriu e resolveu o outro problema

Comment: Consegui resolver, só faltou eu abrir e fechar parenteses dentro do VALUES ?,?,?,? resultando em VALUES(?,?,?,?)...Muito obrigado